# ¿Does a timelike non-orientable surface exist?

Tags: semi-riemannian-geometry, non-orientable-surfaces

Consider the Lorentz-Minkowski space of dimension $3$, $\mathbb{L}^3 = (\mathbb{R}^3,\langle \: \cdot \: \rangle)$
$$
\langle u,v\rangle=u_1v_1 + u_2v_2 - u_3v_3
$$
We say that a surface $S$ is timelike if for every point $p$, its tangent space $T_pS$ contains a timelike vector, ie a vector $w$ such that $\langle w, w\rangle < 0$. I am trying to find an example of such a surface which is not orientable however I think that this is not possible and the clues which lead me to believe this are the following results:

1. If $S$ is compact then it cannot be timelike and all non-orientable surfaces I know of in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are compact.
2. I see no problem with finding a unit normal vector field $N$ by simply parametrizing the surface with $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{L^3}$ and defining
   $$
   N=\frac{\varphi_u \times \varphi_v}{||\varphi_u\times\varphi_v||}
   $$
   This vector field should be smooth.

If you know of an example of such a surface or help me prove that they don't exist it would help me out a lot.

Comment: An open Möbius strip is a non-compact, non-orientable surface in $\mathbb R^3$, but I don't see an embedding that's timelike.

Comment: Surely a differentiable surface with a boundary can be timelike, no? Do you exclude surfaces that have boundaries? What did you have in mind as an example of an unorientable surface in $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: @AndreasBlass What about this embedding: first construct an oval figure in the $x,t$ plane consisting of two long flat strips parallel to the $t$ axis, connected by a half-annulus on the "upper" end and connected by another half-annulus on the "lower" end. Now replace one of the strips by a strip with a half-twist. The width of the strip must be narrow enough that the normal to the surface is always space-like, so the tangent space at that point contains at least one time-like vector. But I am still waiting for clarification on what is actually being asked here.

Comment: @DavidK Your embedding looks good to me.

Comment: @DavidK I am not excluding surfaces with boundaries. I assume that you are taking the $t$ axis as the one generated by the vector $(0,0,1)$ with negative scalar product, right?

Comment: @DavidK It seems to me that with this embedding there should be a point on the surface where one of the principal directions is null. This would lead to also having a null tangent space

Comment: It's an ordinary M&ouml;bius strip as far as I can tell. On most of the surface, the tangent space includes the vector $(0,0,1)$ (and yes, I meant that the $t$ axis is parallel to that vector). Where do you think the null tangent space would occur, specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equip the space $\mathbb L^3$ with $x$-, $y$-, and $t$-axes,
where the $t$ axis is parallel to the vector $(0,0,1),$
that is, it is the time axis.

I propose the following embedding of a Möbius strip.

To construct the embedding, first construct an oval figure in the $x,t$ plane consisting of two long flat strips parallel to the $t$ axis, connected by a half-annulus on the "upper" end and connected by another half-annulus on the "lower" end. Now replace one of the strips by a strip with a half-twist, parallel to the $x,t$ plane at either end. 
The strip must be narrow enough that the normal to the surface is always space-like, so the tangent space at that point contains at least one time-like vector.

I think this surface has the property that for any path that makes a full circuit around the surface (thereby exhibiting the fact that it is unorientable), at least part of the path must be in a timelike direction.
I believe that in order to be non-orientable, a surface needs every path that exhibits its lack of orientation to have a timelike portion.

---

By the way, a simple compact surface that is timelike everywhere (though also orientable) is a flat disk parallel to the $t$ axis.
The first step in my construction (before inserting the half twist)
is cut from such a disk.

---

If you add the restriction that every closed path on your surface must either be able to shrink to a point or be able to be deformed to a purely spacelike path, then I think it is true that the surface must be orientable.

Comment: Yes! This seems to work, I will try to find a parametrization and do the working out.
However, I still do not understand one minor point here, what do you mean by 'narrow enough'? Shouldn't any old strip on the $x,t$ plane work?

Comment: The part that stays in the $x,t$ plane can be as wide as you like. My concern was with the part of the surface where we make the twist. The outer edges of that part of the strip make a kind double helix, and if we make the radius of that helix too large (without also increasing it axial length) we eventually end up inclining those edges so far from vertical that the tangent spaces near the edge become spacelike.